# What is the best way to CRUD children of a field in firebase cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been stuck forever to create many to many relation between user and project. Many people told that array is better than map but I don't really know how to start. So which is better for this one ? I can't submit into projNo's child and can't select the project from the collection "project". The drop-down shows the projNo from "project" collection but I can't change it to a new value.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fire from '../config/Fire';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation';

class EditUser extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.unsubscribe = null;
    this.state = {
      key: '',
      authority: '',
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      projNo: {projNo1: '', projNo2: '', projNo3: ''},
      project: []
    };
  }

  onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const project = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { projNo } = doc.data();
      project.push({
        key: doc.id,
        doc, // DocumentSnapshot
        projNo
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      project
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const ref = fire.firestore().collection('user').doc(this.props.match.params.id);
    ref.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        const user = doc.data();
        this.setState({
          key: doc.id,
          authority: user.authority,
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password,
          projNo: user.projNo
        });
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    });

    this.unsubscribe = fire.firestore().collection('project').onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    const state = this.state
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({user:state});
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { authority, name, email, password, projNo, projNo1, projNo2, projNo3 } = this.state;

    const updateRef = fire.firestore().collection('user').doc(this.state.key);
    updateRef.set({
      authority,
      name,
      email,
      password,
      projNo,
      projNo1,
      projNo2,
      projNo3
    }).then((docRef) => {
      this.setState({
        key: '',
        authority: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        projNo: { projNo1: '', projNo2: '', projNo3: '' }
      });
      this.props.history.push("/show/"+this.props.match.params.id)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
       ...
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditUser;
```

[Image for the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkzZD.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to show that a user is connected to a set of projects then I would switch to an array.

To add and remove projects from an array in firestore you can refer to the firebase docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0#update_elements_in_an_array

So when you create the user just switch to settings an array, like so:

```
updateRef.set({
          authority,
          name,
          email,
          password,
          projNo: [projNo1,projNo2,projNo3]
        })
```

In the future, if you want to atomically add or remove projects from the `projNo` array, this can be achieved like so:

```
// Add
updateRef.update({
    projNo: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("projNo16")
});

// Remove 
updateRef.update({
    projNo: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("projNo1")
});
```

Remember, you will need to import `firebase` into the file where you are calling the above otherwise you can't use FieldValue methods.

Comment: Also, you create a stream called `this.unsubscribe` in componentDidMount but you don't unsubscribe, you should unsubscribe from this when the component unmounts.

Comment: Thanks, but i still can't place a new value to projNo which is currently "01". For example, I want to change it to "04", when I click it on the drop-down list, it is still remain as "01". Another thing, my "onSubmit" causes 3 new fields instead of placing value to projNo's child.

Comment: These are different questions though. Please open a new question and link to it here and I'd give it a shot.  I believe I answered the question you actually asked in my response. Keeping one question per question in stack overflow helps other people with the same problem find and benefit for the solutions.

Comment: Urgently need your help in this matter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55094042/firebaseerror-function-query-where-requires-a-valid-third-argument-but-it-wa