# How to keep multiple data for check boxes in react using firebase cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have problem to store the multiple value for data using check box. Once I click submit button, the values are not stored as array. Only the latest value will be recorded within a single field. When I try to write `behaviour[0]` in `<input>` it appear to be stored as `behavoiur[]` in firebase Database. How to store the data in array correctly ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fire from '../config/Fire';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation';

class CreateForm extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.ref = fire.firestore().collection('form');
    this.state = {
      status: '',
      date: '',
      time: '',
      project: '',
      department: '',
      phone: '',
      detail: '',
      behaviour: [],
      tool: [],
      environment: [],
      action: '',
      photo: '',
      cases: ''
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    // current array of options
    const options = this.state.options
    let index

    // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
    if (e.target.checked) {
      // add the numerical value of the checkbox to options array
      options.push(+e.target.value)
    } else {
      // or remove the value from the unchecked checkbox from the array
      index = options.indexOf(+e.target.value)
      options.splice(index, 1)
    }

    // update the state with the new array of options
    this.setState({ options: options })
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    const state = this.state
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { status, date, time, project, department, phone, detail, behaviour, tool, environment, action, photo, cases } = this.state;

    this.ref.add({
      status,
      date,
      time,
      project,
      department,
      phone,
      detail,
      behaviour,
      tool,
      environment,
      action,
      photo,
      cases
    }).then((docRef) => {
    this.setState({
      status: '',
      date: '',
      time: '',
      project: '',
      department: '',
      phone: '',
      detail: '',
      behaviour: [],
      tool: [],
      environment: [],
      action: '',
      photo: '',
      cases: ''
      });
      this.props.history.push("/form")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { status, date, time, project, department, phone, detail, behaviour, tool, environment, action, photo, cases } = this.state;
    return (
    <div>
    <Navigation />

      <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
            <p></p>
              ADD FORM
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h4><Link to="/form" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</Link></h4>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="status">Status: &nbsp;</label>
                <input type="radio" name="status" value="Unsafe Act" onChange={this.onChange}/> Unsafe Act &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="status" value="Unsafe Condition" onChange={this.onChange}/> Unsafe Condition
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date">Date: </label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value={date} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Select date" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="time">Time: </label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="time" value={time} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Select time" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="project">Project: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="project" value={project} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Select project" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="department">Department: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="department" value={department} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Select department" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone number: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value={phone} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Insert phone number" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="detail">Detail Description of Unsafe Act Unsafe Condition Observed : </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="detail" value={detail} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Insert details" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <br></br>
                <label for="behaviour">People & At Risk Behaviours: </label><br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="behaviour" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value="Annoyance and horseplay in the workplace"/> Annoyance and horseplay in the workplace<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="behaviour" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value="Removing safety guards from the workplace or equipment"/> Removing safety guards from the workplace or equipment<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="behaviour" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value="Improper posture of task"/> Improper posture of task<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="behaviour" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value="Risk of contact with electric  current/ hot surface/ hot water"/> Risk of contact with electric  current/ hot surface/ hot water<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="behaviour" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value="Improper lifting, handling or moving object"/> Improper lifting, handling or moving object<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="behaviour" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value="Working under the effect of alcohol/ drugs etc"/> Working under the effect of alcohol/ drugs etc<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="behaviour" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value="Improper placing and stacking of object and material in dangerous location"/> Improper placing and stacking of object and material in dangerous location<br></br>
                Others:<br></br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="behaviour" value={behaviour} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Insert details"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tool">Tools and Equipment: </label><br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Incorrect use of tools and equipment" /> Incorrect use of tools and equipment<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="No maintenance carried out" /> No maintenance carried out<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Inadequate procedure" /> Inadequate procedure<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Poor design" /> Poor design<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Use of defective tools and equipment" /> Use of defective tools and equipment<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Deviate from procedure" /> Deviate from procedure<br></br>
                Others:<br></br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tool" value={tool} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Insert details"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="environment">Work Environment: </label><br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="environment" value="Poor ventilation" /> Poor ventilation<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="environment" value="Poor housekeeping" /> Poor housekeeping<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="environment" value="Trip hazards" /> Trip hazards<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="environment" value="Poor lighting" /> Poor lighting<br></br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="environment" value="Wet floor" /> Wet floor<br></br>
                Others:<br></br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="environment" value={environment} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Insert details"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="action">Action: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="action" value={action} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Insert action" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="photo">Photo URL: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="photo" value={photo} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Insert photo URL" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cases">Case: &nbsp;</label>
                <input type="radio" name="cases" value="Open" onChange={this.onChange}/> Open &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="cases" value="Close" onChange={this.onChange}/> Close
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CreateForm;
```

What I got :
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOUQr.png)

What I want :
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY2zx.png)

Comment: In your `handleChange` you are accessing ` const options = this.state.options`, but options was never initialised. So if you set a initial value in the `constructor` or access it like ` const options = this.state.options || []`, the error would be gone

Comment: The message was gone, but it still won't store data in array. What shoukd I give the name at the <input> to store into each index ?

Answer (score 0):

*Update 13 Mar 2019*

In your handle change you are setting state to this.state.options, but in your submit handler you are not referencing options.

To fix this don't save value to options, save them to the state value you reference in the submit form.

To do this you will need to pass in the value, so that you know what to update:

```
handleChange(e, groupName) {...}
```

then pass in the checkbox category when you call the method. So for each checkbox in the behaviour group update the handler like so:

```
<input
 type="checkbox"
 name="behaviour"
 onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'behaviour').bind(this)}
 value="Annoyance and horseplay in the workplace" />
```

Then you can use the  groupName value to set the value to the correct key in your state:

```
handleChange(e, groupName) {

    const options = this.state[groupName];

    ...

    this.setState({ [groupName]: options });
  }
```

Now when you submit checked value for behaviour will be logged in the behaviour state key. You can do the same for the other groups. Here is a working example of the above.

https://codesandbox.io/s/r07q7zjlmn?fontsize=14

---

Previously:

Your current form output is

```
{
status: "", 
date: "", 
time: "", 
project: "", 
department: "", 
action: "",
behaviour: [],
cases: "",
date: "",
department: "",
detail: "",
environment: [],
phone: "",
photo: "",
project: "",
status: "",
time: "",
tool: []
}
```

What do you want it to be? Your question is not clear

Comment: You are not making it easy to help you by asking unspecific questions and then pasting a giant amount of code in the question. In the future, you can make it easier for people to help you by creating a reproducable version of your issue on code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/r07q7zjlmn?fontsize=14 and only pasting relevant code. Also, when people do take the time to provide answers as I did on a previous question of yours, it's helpful to mark the answer correct. That way other people can find the solution.

Comment: If you clarify your question and explain what you would like to achieve I want to help.

Comment: I cannot store value in array under `behaviour, environment and tool`. When I click submit with the current coding, it will only save [] in the field. So, I just want it to be in array form. I just edit the pic that I got VS what I want.

Comment: I think my mistake is on  `handleChange(e)`

Comment: Yup, you are using the same onChange handler for text inputs and checkbox inputs. They are handled differently. Now that you know what the problem is search stack overflow or google for how to handle a checkbox state in React. This has been covered many times.

Comment: Actually, I have done it and the above was the result. None of them explain how to store the check box value in firebase cloud firestore, which then I ask it here.

Comment: If you get the shape you want in local state before you submit then you will have no problem saying an array to firebase, it will work no problem, just like all the other values.

Comment: In terms of setting an array to firestore, I have literally I answered your question about this previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994541/what-is-the-best-way-to-crud-children-of-a-field-in-firebase-cloud-firestore/54994890#54994890

Comment: I have tried them in local state and get the result. But when I want to use onSubmit above, it doesn't store in array.

Comment: in your handleChange method you are saving the value to this.state.option, but in your submit handler your are not calling the options value anywhere

Comment: I have done as you said and got this message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` with 2 log `groupName behaviour : Object` and `options : Array(1)`. I am informed that 'Object' is from the older version. Did I take any older version of code somewhere ?

Comment: I am not sure what version of your code you are working on but I posted a link with working code in my update to the response. Maybe try copy and posting from the working demo till you figure out what went wrong.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/r07q7zjlmn?fontsize=14 As you can see here, when you click "Annoyance and horseplay in the workplace" checkbox. It will fill in the value into the "Others" text box. So, what should i write as the "name" in each `<input>` ?

Comment: The problem here is the other's field `    <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="behaviour"
                    value={behaviour}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    placeholder="Insert details"
                  />` You can't treat text inputs and checkbox inputs as the same. This is yet another question now. Please open a new question for this entirely new problem. I believe I have answered and solved this question.