# FirebaseError: Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

`this.unsubscribe = this.refAssign.where(‘email’, ‘==’, this.state.user.email ).onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);`

> FirebaseError: Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument,
>   but it was undefined.

I’ve got this message. What I should write for the third argument as I want it to return each one of the "User" which has the same email as in "Assign" collection ?

Comment: If you log `this.state.user.email` before this assignment, what does is produce?

Comment: it said `user email: undefined`

Comment: That's your problem then, define it before you run a query based on it.

Comment: I have defined it but don't know why it didn't recognize it. Hope there is a way to pm you in real time. Btw, this is my first try in react so I want to apologize if I'm not making any sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a numerous try and error, I've found out that it is not possible to do this using "where" clause

```
`componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe1 = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate1);
    this.unsubscribe2 = this.refAssign.where(‘email’, ‘==’, this.state.user.email ).onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate2);
}`
```

instead of that, I compare it in render using `condition ? true : false`

```
                        {this.state.user.map(user =>
                          <tr>
                            <td><Link to={`/show/${user.key}`}>{user.email}</Link></td>
                            <td>{user.name}</td>
                            <td>{user.authority}</td>
                            <td>
                            {this.state.assign.map(assign =>
                                <p>{assign.email == user.email ? assign.projNo : null }</p>
                            )}
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `this.state.user.email` exists before you call this statement.

Comment: I have declared it in constructor `this.state = {
   user: []
   };` so I'm not sure where is the mistake

Comment: For this to work you are going to have to set the email value on user first.

Comment: You can conditionally render like so `this.unsubscribe = this.state.user && this.state.user.email && this.refAssign...`

Comment: Basically if user doesn't have an email, ther is no way for firebase to know how to filter teh query

Comment: Are you saying that my response to "make sure this.state.user.email exists" didn't help? If you have 3 emails in your user collection, make sure they can be logged before you try and run the function in your question. If you can't then it means you have a different problem that you need to solve before you can deal with this. It is most likely an async issue as there is a delay if you are calling this information form a network. The way around this is to conditionally render the statemnet liek I explained in a comment earlier on this thread.

Comment: If you cant figure out how to access `this.state.user.email` then I would recommend setting up a new question and posting the relevant code so that people can help you. That is a different problem from the one you have posted in this question. I understand that you are new, that's great and welcome to stack overflow. If you learn how to make it easy to help you by asking specific questions, explaining what you have tried, and sharing code to reproduce the problem then you will get much higher response rates to your questions.

Comment: `componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribe2 = this.refAssign.where('email', '==', this.state.user.email).onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate2);
 }` this is the full function code

Comment: Is it possible if I want user.email to become a variable that changes from user to user to be compared with assign.email ?

Comment: The email key on the user object does not exist in your code. If you just want a placeholder then at least set it `this.state = { user: {email: ''} }`. At the moment you are defining `user` as an empty array in state and then trying to call it as an object. Aside from that, posting code in the comment on a response is just being unhelpful. Please open a new question so that everyone can benefit from the discussion. Your original question was 'What I should write for the third argument in a firestore query ' and this is a whole new discussion about a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

// Create a query against the collection.
var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");

Make sure email is not null or empty